Intuition of Transformed Random Variable

Find the PDF of $Y=X^2$ given that the PDF of $X$ is $f(x)=2x,0<x<1$

Calculate the inverse and the derivative:
$$y=x^2\implies x=v(y)=\sqrt{y}\implies v'(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$$
Applying the formula gives the correct answer:
$$f_Y(y)=f_X(v(y))\times |v'(y)|=2\sqrt{y}\times \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}=1, 0<y<1$$
I understand the calculations quite well, and I spent some time on the linked page understanding the derivation of the formula itself.
However, I am having trouble intutively understanding why the square of a random variable with a linear PDF will have a uniform PDF. Is there some logic to this? In general, is there any intution on how the PDF of a function of a random variable is related to the PDF of the random variable itself?

Note $F(x)=x^2$ and apply this theorem - which tells you exactly why $X^2$ is uniform and why it is not a coincidence

@Masacroso What do you mean when you say the distribution doesn't define a random variable?

@Snoop yes, i had read about the probability integral transform, but did not make the connection.

@Masacroso I did not understand your comment. Perhaps you could share some link or context.
